# Showing modal window to active tab only

Tags: c#, winforms

Im working on a c# application, win forms are used. I want to show modal window only to the active tab, currently how it is like if that tab is opened and i moved to other tab without closing that tab pop up related to the tab i havent closed is showing. how can i make pop up show only when im on that tab?

Comment: Replace/overlay the tab contents with a panel showing the content you want in the modal

Comment: `TabControl` has events `Selected` and `Deselected`. You can use them to show and hide the popup window.

Comment: @Dialecticus its for viewing purpose only, so only Tablelayout panels are there

Comment: @Dialectus but if one has shown a modal dialog, how does one "reach" the tab to cause a tab change event that will hide it again.. ?